# How do I properly code my footer? See example

Tags: php, footer, copyright

I would like to code this footer code:

```
<p class="mh-copyright"><?php printf(esc_html__('Copyright &copy; %1$s | Made by %2$s', 'mh-magazine-lite'), date("Y"), '<a href="' . esc_url('https://www.example.com/') . '" rel="nofollow">Dev</a>'); ?></p>
```

So my footer will look something like this (plus Terms of Use and Privacy Policy has hyperlink with "_blank" target in them):

Copyright © 2016 | Made by Dev | Privacy Policy  Terms of Use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code in the footer  ...

```
         <div class="your-class-name">
         <?php _e('Copyright &copy ', 'textdomain'); ?> <?php echo date('Y'); ?>  | <?php _e('Made by Dev ', 'textdomain'); ?>| <a href="#"><?php _e('Privacy Policy Terms of Use', 'textdomain'); ?></a>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It needed a bit more tweaks but it worked.